# ServiceWorkerModule.register with dynamic URL

Tags: angular, typescript, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I’m trying to register the Angular `ServiceWorkerModule` and dynamically pass the URL to the worker script. In my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';

@NgModule({
  // …
  imports: [
    // our setup requires to set this dynamically
    ServiceWorkerModule.register(`${window.baseUrl}/ngsw-worker.js`)
  ]
});
export class AppModule {}
```

Unfortunately, the AOT compiler “optimizes” the variable away and I effectively end up with a string `null/ngsw-worker.js`.

How can I prevent this?